# VBA chart width to page

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I am creating a VBA reporting tool that creates PDF files over specific periods in a pivot table.

I added a pivot table to the print range and a pivot graph. Everything is working perfectly except for the size of the graph. I need to resize the table columns with: `Columns("A:i").EntireColumn.AutoFit` 
but then the chart that needs to start in column A as well, overshoots the print range.
How can I resize my chart to fit the page size instead of linking the size to a column?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could add this to the macro

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Width = Columns("A:I").Width
```

which will make the width of the chart the same as width of the columns. Adjust "A:I" as necessary if the print range is smaller. Or you could have it as wide as print area

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Width = Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea).Width
```